# what is the difference between ResponseEntity<Mono> and Mono<ResponseEntity> as a return type of a rest controller

Tags: spring, mono, response, spring-webflux, flux

In Spring Webflux, what's the difference between ResponseEntity<Mono> versus Mono<ResponseEntity> as a return type of a rest controller?

When is the most appropriate to what?

Following up on this question, let's say I need to return a list, or let's say several elements of Foo, there are many examples of returning Flux.
Would it make sense to return ResponseEntity<Flux> or Flux<ResponseEntity>?

When I'm looking for this question, I found the same question posted here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22614, but no answer, I searched spring docs, but find no info.

Comment: The first returns a ResponseEntity that itself includes a Mono. The other is the reactive way of returning a `ResponseEntity`. The flux sample returns a `ResponseEntity` that writes a `Flux`, the other returns a `Flux` or `ResponseEntity` instances.

Answer (score 32):

Here are the various options you can make with a `ResponseEntity` return value:

- `ResponseEntity<Mono<T>>` or `ResponseEntity<Flux<T>>` -- this makes the response status and headers known immediately while the body is provided asynchronously at a later point. Whether the body is `Mono` or `Flux` depends on how many values the response has.
- `Mono<ResponseEntity<T>>` -- this provides all three -- response status, headers, and body, asynchronously at a later point. IT allows the response status and headers to vary depending on the outcome of asynchronous request handling.
- `Mono<ResponseEntity<Mono<T>>>` or `Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<T>>>` are also possible but less common. They provide the response status and headers asynchronously first and then the response body, also asynchronously at a second point later.

Comment: This was insightful, great answer! However, it is quite confusing in practice. Do you know of any examples which demonstrate the understanding you share in a real world project. I'm dabling with open api generator for Spring Boot using reactive option to create the interface stubs to be implemented. Return signatures are:   

`Mono<ResponseEntity<Game>>`,    `Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>>`,   `Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<ContactDTO>>>` (*most confusing, is this even accurate in your opinion/experience?*). Thanks very much!

Comment: I think that the default return type in the Controller, if you do not specify the `ResponseEntity`, for example `Mono<String>` is `ResponseEntity<Mono<String>>`(option 1)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-responseentity

> WebFlux supports using a single value reactive type to produce the
> ResponseEntity asynchronously, and/or single and multi-value reactive
> types for the body.

So the return type on an annotated controller would actually be a Reactive Publisher like Flux or Mono that emits an object representing the data to return.

Example

```
Flux<AccountDto>
```

Or also:

```
Flux<ResponseEntity<AccountDto>>
```

I think you can even just set a raw DTO type as the return type and Webflux will automagically wrap it in a publisher for you.

**Valid Return Types**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-return-types

Example: https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-spring-webflux-react-example/blob/react-app/reactive-web/src/main/java/com/example/demo/ProfileRestController.java

**Non-blocking Reactive Paradigm**

When doing Reactive Programming you want to every layer to communicate via Flux/Mono.  So you would get back a Flux from your ReactiveRepository and the service layer would also return a Flux to the Controller. Basically, in reactive programming everything is a Flux/Mono.

**Internals**

While SpringMVC and Spring Webflux annotated controllers look similar, they are vastly different internally.  For instance, Webflux uses Jetty while SpringMVC uses Tomcat by default.  Internally, Webflux is more like a non-blocking event-loop architecture while SpringMVC traditionally leverages a threadpool with 1 thread per request blocking for I/O.

Check out this article for more details on [Spring WebFlux](https://medium.com/@anataliocs/basic-introduction-to-spring-webflux-eb155f501b17)